# grails Pagination using iterative gorm querys aggregation

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, offset, pagination

I have this controller.method rendering all things associated to a profile with the correct offset and max for the pagination in the gsp

```
    if (profil) {
        def max = params.max ? params.max as int : 5
        def offset = params.offset ? params.offset as int : 0
        List things = []

        things = Things.findAllByProfil(profil,[max: max, offset: offset, sort: 'dtCreated', order: 'desc'])
        [profil: profil, things: things, thingsCount: things.size()]
    }
```

but now i´m having a special "aggregating-Profile" wich has some profiles associated and i want to put all things of all associated profiles in a list like:

```
    if (profil) {
        def max = params.max ? params.max as int : 5
        def offset = params.offset ? params.offset as int : 0
        List things = []

        if(profil.typ == 'Aggregate'){
            List profiles = profil.profiles?.collect { Profil.collection.findOne(_id:it.id) }
            profiles.each() { pr ->
                if(pr) {
                    things+= Things.findAllByProfil(pr as Profil,[max: max,offset: offset,  sort: 'dtCreated', order: 'desc']) 
                }
            } 
            things.sort{a,b-> b.dtCreated<=>a.dtCreated}
        }else{

            things = Things.findAllByProfil(profil,[max: max, offset: offset, sort: 'dtCreated', order: 'desc'])
        }
        [profil: profil, things: things, thingsCount: things.size()]
    }
```

but this way i´m using the `offset` and `max` several times, for each associated profile, so the resulting list is too big.

unfortunetly the result-design should stay the same, so `assert params.max == 5 && profil.typ == "Aggregate"`, the first-page´s result is a list with the 5 most recent things of all profiles ( as i put them all in a list and sort them by the dtCreated) and my problem maybe : how to apply the same slicing logic to the aggregated list(and how to aggregate the things in a performant way)

What would be the best approach to solve this problem ?

for any hint thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your profile domain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd like to extend on what rcgeorge23 has stated in that you really are better off letting the gorm/database handle your aggregation. [Section 6 of the Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#finders) will take you a long way.

In your particular case, you can simply use a built-in comparator with your `findAllBy to handle your aggregation, here's a concrete example:

```
if(profil.typ == 'Aggregate'){
  List profiles = //some code to get a list of profiles
  def things = Things.findAllByProfilInList(profiles, [max: max....order: 'desc'])
} else {
  ...
}
```

Second, your use of pagination is a little off. thingsCount should technically be a simple "select count" matching your criteria, but you're returning matching criteria limited by "max". So use the following for thingsCount

```
def thingsCount = Things.countByProfilInList(profiles) //for all things with aProfile in list
 or
def thingsCount = Things.countByProfil(aProfile) //for all things with aProfile
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot the "InList" comparator is the perfect solution i was looking for, and thanks for the hint with "thingsCount", I may correct you, I used Things.countBy...

Comment: you're correct, I got a little cut-n-paste happy. I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is very dependent on how you want to display your result on your view. In aggregate mode you are having pagination logic for the number of Things per profile, but I guess what is multiplying the result is the number of associated profiles. So you need to use some sort of pagination for the number of associated profiles.

That is why I am asking how you want to display your result, because that should drive the design.

Assuming you are in Aggregate mode. 
Let say you have a screen that shows all the aggregated profiles, up to here you need a pagination, which currently you dont have, then if users click on each profile to show them the result of Things another pagination mechanism is needed which you already have.

Again depending on your design you might want to separate Profiles list than their Things list. with different action to kind of slice (paginate) your result. In your current design in aggregate mode the problem is `things.size() == profiles.count * max` and you don't have control over profiles size now.

Hope this help

Comment: thanks a lot, that really helps expressing what i need to do, unfortunetly the result-design should stay the same, so assert params.max == 5 && profil.typ == "Aggregate",     the first-page´s result is a list with the 5 most recent things of all profiles ( as i put them all in a list and sort them by the dtCreated) and my problem maybe : how to apply the same slicing logic to the aggregated list(and how to aggregate the things  in a performant way)

Answer (score 1):

I think ideally you'd want to express the `profil.typ == 'Aggregate'` bit of your query using a criteria builder, or HQL, or SQL, or some combination of these that means you're letting the database do the work rather than your application. It would also mean the `max` and `offset` would work correctly.

I don't know what your model looks like, but I think you could do what you want by using a SQL sub-select inside a `sqlRestriction` block. It's difficult to find non-trivial examples online, but the docs [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.2/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) will get you started.